# More than one value from xml file

Tags: powershell

I have a problem.
I need find all files form xml file with exact extensions. 
For example i have this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <ls>
    <files>
      <file>
        <filename value="data.txt" />
      </file>
      <file>
        <filename value="data.csv" />
      </file>
      <file>
        <filename value="data.bkp" />
      </file>
      <file>
        ...
        ...

        ...
        ...
      </file>
    </files>
</session>
```

First time I need get all TXT files, second time all DAT files, third time DAT, XLSX and TXT files etc.

I know how to get files by exact condition.

```
[xml]$files = Get-Content myxmlfile.xml
$files.session.files.file.filename | Where-Object {$_.value -like "*.txt" -or $_.value -like "*.dat" -or etc...}
```

This is perfect solution if condition is still same in the time. 
But if it is still in change? I need dynamic conditions with -or parametter.

Do you know how shall I do it?
Something like this

```
$mystring = "*.txt",*.dat"
$files.session.files.file.filename | Where-Object {$_.value -include $mystring}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regular expressions and `-match` operator. Example:

```
$pattern = '\.(dat|txt)$'
$files.session.files.file.filename | Where-Object { $_.value -match $pattern }
```

Comment: It's exactly what I mean. Thank you.